# Eventmachine gem permission denied

Tags: rubygems, nokogiri, eventmachine

I'm trying to run

```
$gem install eventmachine -v '0.12.10'
```

because when running

```
$bundle install
```

within my rails app, when it gets to eventmachine I get this error:

```
Installing eventmachine (0.12.10) 
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - /Users/pippinlee/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/.gitignore
An error occured while installing eventmachine (0.12.10), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install eventmachine -v '0.12.10'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I have tried adding gem 'eventmachine', '~> 0.12.10' to Gemfile.

As per these (http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html) Nokogiri instructions I've installed libxml2, libxslt, libiconv-1.13.1 files with brew.

Using -pre (and corresponding lock in Gemfile) for the install doesn't differ result either.

**Running: Lion, Xcode 4.3.2, rvm 1.14.10, ruby 1.9.3p194, rails (3.2.7, 3.2.0)**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which is the user you are running bundle from?  and which is the user used to install rvm?  check the permission in your .rvm directory.

Comment: As far as I can tell both are under pippinlee.

It was ask what happens when I $sudo gem install eventmachine -v '0.12.10'

This is the output: [http://pastebin.com/Bfct7wzG]

Appears to be a makefile error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the brute-force approach might work:

```
sudo chown -R pippinlee:staff /Users/pippinlee/.rvm
```

My guess is you did something, like installing another gem, running as the root user by accident.