# Installing Ruby project from Github - bundle install gets ERROR on nokogiri -v '1.5.0'

Tags: ruby, git, bundler, nokogiri

Trying to run Ruby+MongoDb project from Github. Making it happen through README instructions . Get stack when run command "bundle install --path=.bundle
". It argues on "nokogiri -v '1.5.0'". Says that it is impossible to install all the dependencies from Gemfile.

Need to run https://github.com/ai/dis.spbstu.ru on newly installed Ubuntu 13.10 x86

Previously installed through apt-get install:

- git
- Ruby1.9.1
- libxml2-dev
- libxslt1-dev
- mongodb

Not availiable to install, but needed in README file:

- Ruby1.9.1-dev

According to README next step (#9) is "bundle install --path=.bundle", so terminal puts:

```
minstral@minstral-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC:~/dis.spbstu.ru$ bundle install --path=.bundle
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching additional metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
Using rake (0.9.2)
Using multi_json (1.0.3)
Using activesupport (3.1.1)
Using builder (3.0.0)
Using i18n (0.6.0)
Using activemodel (3.1.1)
Using erubis (2.7.0)
Using rack (1.3.4)
Using rack-cache (1.1)
Using rack-mount (0.8.3)
Using rack-test (0.6.1)
Using hike (1.2.1)
Using tilt (1.3.3)
Using sprockets (2.0.2)
Using actionpack (3.1.1)

Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb 
extconf.rb:10: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
checking for libxml/parser.h... yes
checking for libxslt/xslt.h... yes
checking for libexslt/exslt.h... yes
checking for iconv_open() in iconv.h... yes
checking for xmlParseDoc() in -lxml2... yes
checking for xsltParseStylesheetDoc() in -lxslt... yes
checking for exsltFuncRegister() in -lexslt... yes
checking for xmlHasFeature()... yes
checking for xmlFirstElementChild()... yes
checking for xmlRelaxNGSetParserStructuredErrors()... yes
checking for xmlRelaxNGSetParserStructuredErrors()... yes
checking for xmlRelaxNGSetValidStructuredErrors()... yes
checking for xmlSchemaSetValidStructuredErrors()... yes
checking for xmlSchemaSetParserStructuredErrors()... yes
creating Makefile

make
compiling xml_sax_push_parser.c
compiling xml_encoding_handler.c
compiling xml_namespace.c
xml_namespace.c: In function ‘prefix’:
xml_namespace.c:14:13: warning: variable ‘doc’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
   xmlDocPtr doc;
             ^
xml_namespace.c: In function ‘href’:
xml_namespace.c:33:13: warning: variable ‘doc’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
   xmlDocPtr doc;
             ^
compiling xml_element_decl.c
compiling nokogiri.c
nokogiri.c: In function ‘ruby_strdup’:
nokogiri.c:43:31: warning: conversion to ‘size_t’ from ‘int’ may change the sign of the result [-Wsign-conversion]
   char *result = ruby_xmalloc((ssize_t) (len + 1));
                               ^
compiling xml_reader.c
compiling html_document.c
compiling xml_document.c
compiling xml_text.c
compiling xml_element_content.c
compiling xml_cdata.c
compiling xml_document_fragment.c
compiling xml_libxml2_hacks.c
compiling xml_processing_instruction.c
compiling xml_relax_ng.c
compiling xml_comment.c
compiling html_element_description.c
In file included from /usr/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32:0,
                 from ./nokogiri.h:31,
                 from ./html_element_description.h:4,
                 from html_element_description.c:1:
html_element_description.c: In function ‘get_description’:
html_element_description.c:249:40: warning: cast discards ‘__attribute__((const))’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wcast-qual]
   return Data_Wrap_Struct(klass, 0, 0, (void *)description);
                                        ^
/usr/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:818:35: note: in definition of macro ‘Data_Wrap_Struct’
     rb_data_object_alloc((klass),(sval),(RUBY_DATA_FUNC)(mark),(RUBY_DATA_FUNC)(free))
                                   ^
compiling xml_dtd.c
compiling xml_schema.c
compiling xml_xpath_context.c
xml_xpath_context.c: In function ‘xpath_generic_exception_handler’:
xml_xpath_context.c:184:3: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
   rb_raise(rb_eRuntimeError, message);
   ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make: *** [xml_xpath_context.o] Ошибка 1


Gem files will remain installed in /home/minstral/dis.spbstu.ru/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.5.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/minstral/dis.spbstu.ru/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.5.0/ext/nokogiri/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.5.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.5.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Then everytime I call install bundle again terminal puts:

```
minstral@minstral-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC:~/dis.spbstu.ru$ bundle install --path=.bundle
/home/minstral/dis.spbstu.ru/Gemfile:39:in `eval_gemfile': uninitialized constant Bundler::Dsl::YAML (NameError)
       /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:30:in `instance_eval'
       /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:30:in `eval_gemfile'
       /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:9:in `evaluate'
       /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:26:in `build'
       /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler.rb:152:in `definition'
       /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:253:in `install'
       /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
       /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:121:in `invoke_command'
       /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:363:in `dispatch'
       /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
       /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:10:in `start'
       /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.5.3/bin/bundle:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
       /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:5:in `with_friendly_errors'
       /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.5.3/bin/bundle:20:in `<top (required)>'
       /usr/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
       /usr/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
There was an error in your Gemfile, and Bundler cannot continue.
```

Gemfile.lock has this:

```
GEM   remote: http://rubygems.org/   specs:
    actionmailer (3.1.1)
      actionpack (= 3.1.1)
      mail (~> 2.3.0)
    actionpack (3.1.1)
      activemodel (= 3.1.1)
      activesupport (= 3.1.1)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
      rack (~> 1.3.2)
      rack-cache (~> 1.1)
      rack-mount (~> 0.8.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
      sprockets (~> 2.0.2)
    activemodel (3.1.1)
      activesupport (= 3.1.1)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
    activerecord (3.1.1)
      activemodel (= 3.1.1)
      activesupport (= 3.1.1)
      arel (~> 2.2.1)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activeresource (3.1.1)
      activemodel (= 3.1.1)
      activesupport (= 3.1.1)
    activesupport (3.1.1)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    arel (2.2.1)
    bson (1.4.0)
    bson_ext (1.4.0)
    builder (3.0.0)
    chunky_png (1.2.5)
    coffee-rails (3.1.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (~> 3.1.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.1.2)
    compass (0.12.alpha.0)
      chunky_png (~> 1.2)
      fssm (>= 0.2.7)
      sass (~> 3.1)
    daemons (1.1.4)
    diff-lcs (1.1.3)
    email_validator (1.2.4)
      activemodel
    erubis (2.7.0)
    eventmachine (0.12.10)
    execjs (1.2.9)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    fabrication (1.2.0)
    fssm (0.2.7)
    haml (3.1.3)
    hike (1.2.1)
    i18n (0.6.0)
    json (1.6.1)
    kramdown (0.13.3)
    libv8 (3.3.10.2)
    mail (2.3.0)
      i18n (>= 0.4.0)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    mime-types (1.16)
    mongo (1.4.0)
      bson (= 1.4.0)
    mongoid (2.3.0)
      activemodel (~> 3.1)
      mongo (~> 1.4)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.22)
    multi_json (1.0.3)
    nokogiri (1.5.0)
    oa-core (0.3.0)
    oa-openid (0.3.0)
      oa-core (= 0.3.0)
      rack-openid (~> 1.3.1)
      ruby-openid-apps-discovery (~> 1.2.0)
    oily_png (1.0.2)
      chunky_png (~> 1.2.1)
    polyglot (0.3.2)
    r18n-core (0.4.11)
    rack (1.3.4)
    rack-cache (1.1)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-mount (0.8.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    rack-openid (1.3.1)
      rack (>= 1.1.0)
      ruby-openid (>= 2.1.8)
    rack-ssl (1.3.2)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.1)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.1.1)
      actionmailer (= 3.1.1)
      actionpack (= 3.1.1)
      activerecord (= 3.1.1)
      activeresource (= 3.1.1)
      activesupport (= 3.1.1)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.1.1)
    railties (3.1.1)
      actionpack (= 3.1.1)
      activesupport (= 3.1.1)
      rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (~> 0.14.6)
    rake (0.9.2)
    rdoc (3.9.4)
    rspec (2.6.0)
      rspec-core (~> 2.6.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 2.6.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 2.6.0)
    rspec-core (2.6.4)
    rspec-expectations (2.6.0)
      diff-lcs (~> 1.1.2)
    rspec-mocks (2.6.0)
    rspec-rails (2.6.1)
      actionpack (~> 3.0)
      activesupport (~> 3.0)
      railties (~> 3.0)
      rspec (~> 2.6.0)
    ruby-openid (2.1.8)
    ruby-openid-apps-discovery (1.2.0)
      ruby-openid (>= 2.1.7)
    sass (3.1.10)
    sass-rails (3.1.4)
      actionpack (~> 3.1.0)
      railties (~> 3.1.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.4)
      sprockets (~> 2.0.0)
      tilt (~> 1.3.2)
    sprockets (2.0.2)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    therubyracer (0.9.8)
      libv8 (~> 3.3.10)
    thin (1.2.11)
      daemons (>= 1.0.9)
      eventmachine (>= 0.12.6)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    thor (0.14.6)
    tilt (1.3.3)
    treetop (1.4.10)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    tzinfo (0.3.30)
    uglifier (1.0.3)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.0.2)
    visibilityjs (0.4)
      sprockets (>= 2.0.0.beta.5)
    wirble (0.1.3)

PLATFORMS   ruby

DEPENDENCIES   bson_ext   coffee-rails   compass (~> 0.12.alpha)   email_validator   fabrication   haml   json   kramdown   mongoid   nokogiri   oa-openid   oily_png   r18n-core   rails (= 3.1.1)   rspec-rails   sass-rails   therubyracer   thin   uglifier   visibilityjs   wirble
```

Gemfile has this:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.1.1'

gem 'mongoid'
gem 'bson_ext'

gem 'json'
gem 'haml'
gem 'nokogiri'

gem 'oa-openid'
gem 'email_validator'

gem 'kramdown'
gem 'r18n-core'

gem 'visibilityjs'

group :assets do
  gem 'compass', '~> 0.12.alpha'
  gem 'sass-rails'
  gem 'coffee-rails'
  gem 'uglifier'
  gem 'therubyracer'
end

group :development do
  gem 'oily_png'
  gem 'wirble'
  gem 'thin'
end

group :test, :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'fabrication'
end

YAML::ENGINE.yamler = 'psych' # Исправляем ошибку Bundler
```

!BUT if I delete line "YAML::ENGINE... etc" in Gemfile, then everytime when I call "install bundle... etc" I get only first message "Fetching gem metadata... etc"

How-to go with this problem? Bundle install don't want to work

Comment: Checked the problem with nokogiri. In Gemfile.lock changed version of nokogiri to 1.5.6 (last 1.6.1 version fails as 1.5.0).
Now have the same problem (an error has occured while installing eventmachine -v '0.12.10')

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eventmachine gem permission denied](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11751761/eventmachine-gem-permission-denied)